# redirect index.php when accessed directly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was trying to setup my .htaccess to redirect any traffic which went directly to my index.php without a valid query string.

When I say valid I mean: /index.php?page=home

So if they go directly to index.php it will redirect to /

Here is my .htaccess

```
options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([/a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)(/|)$ /index.php?page=$1$2 [QSA,L]
```

I am not sure it's possible?

Comment: Why should't that be possible? The issue here, as far as I can see, is that you do not check for any query parameters, nor do you check if index.php has been called without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this. Check for any query is not there then redirect to root. That should be the simplest form. This is providing that all your links have query strings.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 RewriteRule ^index\.php / [NC,QSA,L]
```

that should do

Answer (score 0):

I think with Apache RewriteRule you can't match the query string (what comes after ?)

page.html?a=2&b=5

The part ?a=2&b=5 can't be matched with Apache RewriteRule. You can match only page.html and you have the option to include/enable the query string by using the QSA flag. Otherwise the query string will be ignored.

RewriteRule ^page.html my-page.php [QSA]

And then you can read the query string from PHP, by using parse_url() or just $_GET.

Comment: The query string is checkable, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html.

Answer (score 0):

This will require a query string and the page being requested is '' or 'index.php'. It will redirect to a.php if that is the case.

```
options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(index.php|)$
RewriteRule .* a.php [R=301,L]
```